# Extend an action of indeterminates to an action of field of rational functions

Tags: galois-theory, group-actions, profinite-groups

In [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwih6L3fzpbuAhXE-qQKHZDBCioQFjAGegQIDhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwwwen.uni.lu%2Fcontent%2Fdownload%2F75427%2F940970%2Ffile%2FRibes.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3r_vuvyIld73EJpo3zP_7R) text in the theorem 1.15 the author constructs a Galois extension using group action. In his construction, I can see why $G$ can be seen as an automorphism group of $K$, but I cannot see why the elements are $F$-automorphisms. How can I see that the induced action keep fixed the elements of $F$? Because the structure of $F$ is different from $G$, I'm confused about the extended action of $F(T)$.

Comment: $T$ is a collection of variables and $g\in G$ permutes $T$ so it is clearly a $F$-automorphism of $F(T)$

Comment: @reuns I cannot see how the elements of $G$ act on $F$. If $g \in G$, then $g$ maps an $f \in F$ to itself?

Comment: It is the same as the automorphism of $\Bbb{C}(x,y)$ swapping $x,y$ except that $g$ is swapping/permuting infinitely many variables. Of course it acts trivially on $F$, it only permutes the variables (the elements of $F(T)$ are rational functions in many variables).

Comment: @reuns oh, I got it! Thank you very much.